# Using quadratic terms in r caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I have this code that I use to create an artifitial data set:

```
N=200
X1 <- rnorm(N);
X2 <- rnorm(N);

smallData <- data.frame(Y=1+X1+2*X2+3*X1*X2 + rnorm(N), X1=X1, X2=X2)
```

On which I now use `caret` to learn a linear model. I want to include second order factors as well as linear, i.e. I am looking for a model of the type

```
Y= a*X1 + b*X2 + c*X1*X2 + d
```

And I can do that in two ways (both shown in the code below).

```
trainCtrl <- trainControl(method='cv', number=10, savePredictions=TRUE);
set.seed(1);
smallModel1 <- train(Y~X1+X2+X1*X2, data=smallData, trControl=trainCtrl, method='glm');

smallData$X1X2=X1*X2
set.seed(1);
smallModel2 <- train(Y~., data=smallData, trControl=trainCtrl, method='glm');
```

Both calls return the same model, i.e. the coefficients and RMSE values are the same.

---

However, let's say I also want to include factors for `X1*X1`, i.e. I have

```
smallData <- data.frame(Y=1+X1+2*X2+3*X1*X1 + rnorm(N), X1=X1, X2=X2)
```

(note that now I have `X1*X1` instead of `X1*X2`)

If I run the same code as before, i.e.

```
trainCtrl <- trainControl(method='cv', number=10, savePredictions=TRUE);
set.seed(1);
smallModel1 <- train(Y~X1+X2+X1*X1, data=smallData, trControl=trainCtrl, method='glm');
smallData$X1X1=X1*X1
set.seed(1);
smallModel2 <- train(Y~., data=smallData, trControl=trainCtrl, method='glm');
```

Now, `smallModel2` **STILL** fits a good function, but `smallModel1` fails completely. Any thoughts?

---

I suspect that the problem is my misuse of the symbol `*`. I assumed it simply meant "use the product of these two columns* or something similar, but apparently it does not. There is **no** mention of how to write formulas in the entire `caret` manual, at leas as far as I can see it. I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X1*X1` is not a quadratic term in formula terms. It indicates interactions. X1*X1 in the formula translates itself to `X1 + X1 + X1:X1`.

If you want a quadratic term you need to use `I(X1^2)`

see all formula interactions on [this website](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/formulae.html)

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what the word `interaction` here means, exactly? Because my example clearly shows that if the two vectors are different, the "interaction" is precisely the product of the two, while if they are the same vector, it literally does nothing.

Comment: @5xum, In this case the interaction is X1:X1, but the model will ignore this and just use X1. E.g. `lm(formula(mpg ~ hp*hp), data = mtcars)` just calculates hp and not hp interacting with hp.

Comment: I understand that. But what does **interaction** mean? Like, mathematically? It's not a product, but it's something that behaves exactly like a product some of the time, which is very confusing.

Comment: Two variables interact when the effect of one of them depends on the level of the other's. Check out this for more information http://courses.washington.edu/smartpsy/interactions.htm

Comment: @GeorgeDontas OK, got that. But caret is used to build models. It builds models out of basically tables of rows and columns. And I understand that if I put `X1*X2` into the equation, the result is the same as putting `X1,X2,X1*X2` into the data columns. I am asking, basically, what I need to put into the equation so that it will be equivalent to putting `X1*X1` into the data.

Comment: You need to put `I(X1^2)`. Check out Chapter 11 here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Comment: You can also use `poly(X1, 2)` instead of `X1 + I(X1^2)`.